# error on calling static method from void java

Tags: java, oop

Need help on calling a method from main class.

I need to call a method, thus I made an object to handle it.
below I quote my main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SLRatio sl= new SLRatio();
        sl.clustering(apa);
}
```

and here's the method I need to call

```
public class SLRatio {

public static String [][]clustering(String[][]apa) {

   System.out.println("Cluster 1");

   int a = apa.length/3;
   String [][] cluster1=new String [a][apa[0].length];

   for (int i =0; i<a; i++) {
      for (int j=0;j<apa[0].length;j++) {
         cluster1 [i][j] = apa[i][j];
      }
   }

   for (int b = 0; b < cluster1.length; b++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < cluster1[0].length; c++) {
         System.out.print(cluster1[b][c] + "\t");
       }

       System.out.println("");        
   }

   System.out.println("\n");

   return cluster1;

}
}
```

and I got error message:
"Cannot find symbol,Accessing static method clustering"

What can I do to solve it? I have tried to change the syntax but it didn't work.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I removed the tag [tag:cluster-analysis] because it is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't define method `Allocation()` in `SLRatio`

Note: static method should be called with classname (to avoid confision between instance method and static)

Comment: +1 The "error message" seems to be an error followed by a separate warning.

Comment: I also have tried that way but it still error. no problem with Allocation() method, it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

If it is static method, you don't need to call it through instance.

```
SLRatio .clustering(...);
```

should be enough.

And it seems you forgot to implement `Allocation` method.

Another suggestion, java naming convention, method name starts with small case letters.

Comment: I have tried this way but error message said "Can not find symbol"  is there anything I could do?

Comment: I would suggest, remove both method calls. First add only clusterting method call and see it is working or not. Allocation fails because you don't have method name Allocation in SLRatio class.

Comment: yes i also have run that way and it works. no problem in method Allocation. I also have deactivate the method Allocation calling but it encounter the same error. I also already change the code into "sl.clustering(apa);" but it still encounter error

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `static` unless you are sure it is appropriate.

This is a popular programming error, partially because eclipse keeps on suggesting to make variables and methods `static` when they cannot be accessed. But usually, this is not the correct solution. While it fixes the compilation problem, it often breaks the application logic.

Right now, your problem probably is that `apa` has type `String[][]`, but you are passing a `String[]` parameter to it. So it cannot be compiled, because **there is no method `clustering(String[] args)`**.

Seriously, you need to learn more Java basics. Maybe from a **book**.